# Object-c/iOS :How to use ASynchronous to get a data from URL?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

My friend saw my code, a part is get a plist data from URL

And he told me not to use Synchronous,Use ASynchronous

But I don't know how to do ASynchronous in simple way

This is the code I use in my program

```
NSURL *theURL =  [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://someurllink.php" ];
NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:theURL
                                          cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                          timeoutInterval:60.0];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:theRequest returningResponse:nil error:nil]; 
NSString *listFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];   
self.plist = [listFile propertyList];
[self.tableView reloadData];
[listFile autorelease];
```

How can I change my code use ASynchronous to get the data ?

Great thanks for all reply and answers : )

Comment: works but the approach is outdated

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Short answer**: You can use

```
+ (NSURLConnection *)connectionWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request delegate:(id)delegate;
```

See NSURLConnectionDelegate for the informal delegate protocol (all methods are optional)

**Long answer**:

Downloading data asynchronously is not as straightforward as the synchronous method. First you have to create your own data container e.g. a file container

```
//under documents folder/temp.xml
file = [[SomeUtils getDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.xml"]
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:file]) {
  [fileManager createFileAtPath:file contents:nil attributes:nil];
}
```

When you connect to server:

```
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];
```

You have to fill the container with the data you receive asynchronously:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
  NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:file];
  [fileHandle seekToEndOfFile];
  [fileHandle writeData:data];
  [fileHandle closeFile];
}
```

You have to manage errors encountered using:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
```

If you want to capture the server response:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
```

Handle when connection finished loading:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Comment: May I ask one more question is What about if I want to get a plist data from URL link every 3 seconds to reload ,the code I use will due to memory leak ???or do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: 3 seconds is a very small interval for a continuous server transaction.  Why do you need to do this?  If you have to do this then you might want to ensure first that the previous connection finished loading first or CANCEL the previous connection first before doing the same transaction.

Comment: I think I make a very big mistake,every 3 sec to do this is because of I need to refresh the view with data update ,now I change the code like this :- (void)refreshTheView{ NSURL *theURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"https://theurllink.php"];
 NSArray *receivePlistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:plistURL];}

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous fetch of HTML source code, I recommend you to use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/)

1) Then subclass AFHTTPCLient, for example:

```
//WebClientHelper.h
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@interface WebClientHelper : AFHTTPClient{

}

+(WebClientHelper *)sharedClient;

@end

//WebClientHelper.m
#import "WebClientHelper.h"
#import "AFHTTPRequestOperation.h"

NSString *const gWebBaseURL = @"http://dummyBaseURL.com/";


@implementation WebClientHelper

+(WebClientHelper *)sharedClient
{
    static WebClientHelper * _sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedClient = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:gWebBaseURL]];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (!self) {
        return nil;
    }

    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFHTTPRequestOperation class]];
    return self;
}
@end
```

2) Request asynchronously HTML source code, put this code in any relevant part

```
NSString *testNewsURL = @"http://whatever.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:testNewsURL];
    NSURLRequest *request  = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operationHttp =
    [[WebClientHelper sharedClient] HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
     {
         NSString *szResponse = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
         NSLog(@"Response: %@", szResponse );
     }
     failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"Operation Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
     }];

    [[WebClientHelper sharedClient] enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operationHttp];
```