# iphone execute php url

Tags: php, iphone, url

Beginner question - I have a full URL (in an NSString variable "temp") which I want the application to execute in the background once the user finishes a flow in my iPhone app. I'm having a bit of a problem getting anything to work.

Basically I need to (1) execute the php URL
and
(2) capture the response and display it back to the user.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed before. Here is a good tutorial [web requests](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/09/cocoa-application-driven-by-http-data.html)

In essence, you need [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 0):

This answer hold all the clues :)

[Object-c/iOS :How to use ASynchronous to get a data from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505623/object-c-ios-how-to-use-asynchronous-to-get-a-data-from-url)

Answer (score 0):

In brief, something like the following.  The keys being:

1. have the url of the content you want
2. use dataWithContentsOfURL to get the actual byes
3. create a file
4. save the image bytes

   ```
   If (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationAddress stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]])
   {
     NSError** error;
     NSData* imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:srcAddress] options:NSDataReadingMapped error:error];
     if (imageData != NULL)
    {
       BOOL fileCreated = [fileManager createFileAtPath:destinationAddress contents:imageData attributes:nil];

     }
   ```

   }

Also, use NSURLConnection, if you want to download off the main UI thread (good idea)