# How to show image loaded from a url on a button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Here is an example :
Show multi image on multi button and show on scrollview

```
  (void)viewDidLoad
  {  
[super viewDidLoad];
 NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
InitData *inData=[[InitData alloc]init];


scrollview.delegate=self;
scrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
int scrollWidth = 120;
scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,100);


int xOffset = 0;
//imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imagesName objectAtIndex:0]];

//Test
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"....."];
NSData *jsonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


if (jsonData !=nil)
{

        NSError *error=nil;
        id result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        if (error ==nil)
        {
                NSLog(@"%@",result);
              //  NSMutableArray *ArImg = nil;
               NSArray* rus=[result objectForKey:@"RespOBJ"];

    for (int index = 0; index < rus.count ; index++)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* final=[rus  objectAtIndex:index];

        [inData setId:(int)[final objectForKey:@"Id"]];
        [inData setTum:[final objectForKey:@"TumbImage"]];
        [inData setImage:[final objectForKey:@"Image"]];

        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[inData getImage]] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];
        //[btn setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:jsonData] forState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

        [btn setTag:index];
        btn.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 160, 70);

        scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,70);

        NSLog(@"%@",[inData getId]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[inData getImage]);
        NSLog(@"%@",[inData getTum]);

        [btn addTarget:self
             action: @selector(btnclick:)
             forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [scrollview addSubview:btn];

    xOffset += 170;
```

}

Comment: And...? What's the result of your code?

Comment: result right by used NSLog...but in UI scrollview is empty

Comment: Do you want to set your buttons like photo gallery ????

Comment: yes i do...can u help me

Comment: my coding that's right?! yes or no

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are not loading anything. I assume you want to download the image from the Internet and then display it on the scrollview. To do so, you have to use a `NSURLRequest` and a `NSURLConnection`. 
Have a look at Apple's documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html
You might also like this question on how to load data asynchronously [Object-c/iOS :How to use ASynchronous to get a data from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505623/object-c-ios-how-to-use-asynchronous-to-get-a-data-from-url)

Comment: but i can taking data from url ..but i can show data in scrollview..do you understand me?

Comment: Ok then how do you store the data in your InitData object ? I see you set the image to it `[inData setImage:[final objectForKey:@"Image"]];
`, but is it a link ? some data ? Whatever it is you cannot use `[UIImage imageNamed:]` method to load it ! Try instead `[UIImage imageWithData:]`