# How to load JSON asynchronously (iOS)

Tags: ios, json

My app parses information from a Rails app using JSON. I'm looking for a way to load the JSON asynchronously, but I'm having trouble getting my code to work with examples I have found because of the complexity of my code. What do I have to do to make my JSON load asynchronously? Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *upcomingReleaseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:upcomingReleaseURL];

    NSError *error = nil;

    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    NSArray *upcomingReleasesArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"upcoming_releases"];

    //This is the dateFormatter we'll need to parse the release dates
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSTimeZone *est = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"EST"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:est];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]]; //A bit of an overkill to avoid bugs on different locales

    //Temp array where we'll store the unsorted bucket dates
    NSMutableArray *unsortedReleaseWeek = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableDictionary *tmpDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *upcomingReleaseDictionary in upcomingReleasesArray) {

        //We find the release date from the string
        NSDate *releaseDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"]];

        //We create a new date that ignores everything that is not the actual day (ignoring stuff like the time of the day)
        NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
        NSDateComponents *components =
        [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:releaseDate];

        //This will represent our releases "bucket"
        NSDate *bucket = [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

        //We get the existing objects in the bucket and update it with the latest addition
        NSMutableArray *releasesInBucket = [tmpDict objectForKey:bucket];
        if (!releasesInBucket){
            releasesInBucket = [NSMutableArray array];
            [unsortedReleaseWeek addObject:bucket];
        }

        UpcomingRelease *upcomingRelease = [UpcomingRelease upcomingReleaseWithName:[upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_name"]];
        upcomingRelease.release_date = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"];
        upcomingRelease.release_price = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_price"];
        upcomingRelease.release_colorway = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_colorway"];
        upcomingRelease.release_date = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"release_date"];
        upcomingRelease.thumb = [upcomingReleaseDictionary valueForKeyPath:@"thumb"];
        upcomingRelease.images = [upcomingReleaseDictionary objectForKey:@"images"];
        [releasesInBucket addObject:upcomingRelease];
        [tmpDict setObject:releasesInBucket forKey:bucket];
    }

    [unsortedReleaseWeek sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSDate* date1 = obj1;
        NSDate* date2 = obj2;
        //This will sort the dates in ascending order (earlier dates first)
        return [date1 compare:date2];
        //Use [date2 compare:date1] if you want an descending order
    }];

    self.releaseWeekDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:tmpDict];
    self.releaseWeek = [NSArray arrayWithArray:unsortedReleaseWeek];

}
```

Comment: Note that if viewDidLoad initiates the download, you will need to somehow cause the end of the download to "refresh" your view, since the download will end after viewDidLoad has already returned.

Answer (score 7):

One *simple* approach is to use `NSURLConnection`'s convenient class method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:error`.

The following code snippet is an example how to load a JSON from a server, and where the completion handler executes on a background thread which parses the JSON. It also performs all recommended error checking:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSOperationQueue* queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
                                   queue:queue
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response,
                                           NSData* data,
                                           NSError* error)
{
    if (data) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
        // check status code and possibly MIME type (which shall start with "application/json"):
        NSRange range = [response.MIMEType rangeOfString:@"application/json"];

        if (httpResponse.statusCode == 200 /* OK */ && range.length != 0) {
            NSError* error;
            id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
            if (jsonObject) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // self.model = jsonObject;
                    NSLog(@"jsonObject: %@", jsonObject);
                });
            } else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //[self handleError:error];
                    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
                });
            }
        }
        else {
            // status code indicates error, or didn't receive type of data requested
            NSString* desc = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"HTTP Request failed with status code: %d (%@)",
                              (int)(httpResponse.statusCode),
                              [NSHTTPURLResponse localizedStringForStatusCode:httpResponse.statusCode]];
            NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"HTTP Request"
                                                 code:-1000
                                             userInfo:@{NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: desc}];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //[self handleError:error];  // execute on main thread!
                NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
            });
        }
    }
    else {
        // request failed - error contains info about the failure
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //[self handleError:error]; // execute on main thread!
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
        });
    }
}];
```

Although, it appears somewhat elaborate, IMO this is a minimalistic and still naïve approach. Among other disadvantages, the main issues are:

- it lacks the possibility to cancel the request, and
- there is no way to handle more sophisticated authentication.

A more sophisticated approach needs to utilize `NSURLConnection` *delegates*. Usually, third party libraries do implement it in this manner, encapsulating the a `NSURLConnection` request and other relevant state info into a subclass of `NSOperation`. You may start with your own implementation, for example using [this code](https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/5764723) as a template.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of your `dispatch_async` calls here? If I am understanding correctly, this block is being placed in a queue that was made as part of the main thread so it should be executed on same thread as the main_queue anyway, right?

Comment: @CodeCommander The completion block of convenience class method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` will be executed on the specified _queue_. _queue_ is a `NSOperationQueue` which has been created using `[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]` which uses a "private execution context", that is - it is NOT the main thread. You can read more in the official documentation for `NSOperationQueue` and `NSURLConnection`. ;)

Comment: I see, and if you pass the result of `dispatch_get_main_queue()` as the queue to `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` would that cause your main thread to block while waiting for the request? (defeating the purpose of the async call)

Comment: You would use `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` to obtain the NSOperationQueue which executes its operations on the main thread. This would not "block" the main thread for the whole operation, but when the handler gets executed on the main thread, other events scheduled on the main thread's run loop will have to wait for execution unil the handler finished. Thus, you should ensure your handler does not (synchronously) perform lengthy tasks.

Comment: The line NSMutableURLRequest* urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; should read     NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to get this only json data, you do not need to set up  a lot of things.

use the code below. Create jsonParse method which gets a NSData Object.

```
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://obscure-lake-7450.herokuapp.com/upcoming.json"]];
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [self jsonParse:data];

    });
});
```

Comment: Why not using `NSURLConnection`s convenient class method `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler`: [NSURLConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:)?  While this would be still a naïve approach, there is at least better error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Download your data async as in this answer: [Object-c/iOS :How to use ASynchronous to get a data from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505623/object-c-ios-how-to-use-asynchronous-to-get-a-data-from-url)

Then run it through the json parser.

Comment: Also, I'd recommend to do all the JSON parsing and objects creation on another thread. It'd be best to init `gregorian` only once (not in the loop), as `NSCalendar`s are slow to init.

Answer (score 0):

To generically run code in a background thread you can use this method:

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
     // Code here is run on a background thread

     dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          // Code here is run on the main thread (the UI thread) after your code above has completed so you can update UI after the JSON call has completed if you need to.
     });
 });
```

But remember that Apple does not allow you to update UI elements in a background thread. Also, they do not allow you to spawn more threads from a background thread, it must be done from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *urlstr=@"http://itunes.apple.com/in/rss/topsongs/limit=25/json";
NSMutableURLRequest *request=[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse* response,
                                           NSData* data, NSError* error)
{
    NSError *myError = nil;
    NSDictionary *dic1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&myError];

    if (myError ==nil) {
        NSDictionary*feed =[dic1 objectForKey:@"feed"];
        NSArray*arrayofentry =[feed objectForKey:@"entry"];

        for(NSDictionary *dic2 in arrayofentry) {
            requestReply=[dic2 objectForKey:@"title"];
            [arr1 addObject:requestReply];
        }
        [self.table reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Maybe you can shortly explain what you are doing?

Comment: This approach has two issues: 1) Checking the out parameter `myError` is not the correct way to check if the method `JSONObjectWithData` failed. Instead, you need to check the _return value_, that is, check if `dic1` equals `nil`, then _and only then_ you can access the out parameter `myError`. Otherwise, the method was successful. 2) The completion handler executes on a private queue (due to `queue: [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init`) - that is, the code does not execute on the main thread - and `[self.table reloadData]` will crash - since UIKit methods shall not run on none-main threads. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
        NSURL * inkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"your url"];
        NSURLRequest * request = [[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:inkURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.0];
        NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * response, NSData * data, NSError * error) {
            NSData * jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:inkURL];
            NSDictionary * dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
            self.inkArray = [dataDictionary objectForKey:@"users"];


        }];
```