# Passing parameters makes the code run "slower"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsattributedstring

## Background Information

Currently I'm setting the text for each `UITableViewCell` in my `UITableView` using the following code:

#### Scenario A:

`cell.textLabel.attributedText = [news formattedSubject];`

However, consider if I were to add a parameter for the `formattedSubject` definition, just a single integer parameter so the code is now:

#### Scenario B:

`cell.textLabel.attributedText = [news formattedSubject:1];`

The text in each table view cell is roughly 3-5 lines in length, and is read from an external source and parsed via JSON. Here's a diagram of the **desired result, which is what happens in Scenario A**:

#### Scenario A Flow Diagram:

[image]

Image A simply displays the default, empty `UITableView` that I get when the app is still loading the JSON data. After the app retrieves and parses this data, it then populates the data into the `UITableView`, which results in Image B. **This is the desired (and expected) result.**

However, if I add a parameter to `formattedSubject`, I instead get the flow diagram below:

#### Scenario B Flow Diagram:

[image]

Once again, Image A displays the default `UITableView`. However, it is what happens in Image B that is the problem. **In Image B, the data has been parsed, but has not yet been formatted properly by `formattedSubject`, thus resulting in a single, horizontally-narrow, and lengthy row of unformatted text.** After a fraction of a second, the app looks like Image C, the end result which displays the formatted data after it has been parsed.

## My question:

The only change I made is the addition of a parameter to `formattedSubject`. **That is, I changed `-(NSAttributedString*)formattedSubject {` to `-(NSAttributedString*)formattedSubject:(int)state {`.** It doesn't matter that there is nothing within `formattedSubject` that actually *uses* the `state` integer, I'm still getting the results from Scenario B.

#### This change seems to make the code run more slowly. It creates a delay between when the data is parsed and when it is formatted and displayed in the `UITableView`. I'm curious as to why this is, and how I can fix/circumvent this issue.

Aside from being an aesthetics issue, what happens in **Scenario B** also interferes with my automatic loading of new data when the user reaches the end of the `UITableView`. Because of horizontally-narrowed rows of text, the last row of data will momentarily be displayed in the `UITableView` when it is first loaded, **thus causing data to be retrieved twice upon app startup**.

I am nowhere close to an expert in coding, and thus it makes absolutely no sense to me how simply adding a parameter to my `NSAttributedString` could create the aforementioned delay. I would be very appreciative if someone could:

1. Explain **why** this is happening, and
2. Offer a solution to resolve this issue.

Thank you very much for reading this, any and all comments/help is welcomed.

## Edit 1: @Vijay-Apple-Dev.blogspot.com, @txulu

Here is my **`formattedSubject`** code:

```
-(NSAttributedString*)formattedSubject:(int)state {
    if(formattedSubject!=nil) return formattedSubject;
    NSDictionary *boldStyle = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    if(state==1) {
        boldStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.067 green:0.129 blue:0.216 alpha:1.0]};
    }
    else {
        boldStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
    }
    NSDictionary* normalStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]};
    NSMutableAttributedString* articleAbstract = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:subject];
    [articleAbstract setAttributes:boldStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, subject.length)];
    [articleAbstract appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];
    int startIndex = [articleAbstract length];
    NSTimeInterval _interval=[datestamp doubleValue];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:_interval];
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [_formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    NSString* description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@ on %@",author,[_formatter stringFromDate:date]];
    [articleAbstract appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: description]];
    [articleAbstract setAttributes:normalStyle range:NSMakeRange(startIndex, articleAbstract.length - startIndex)];
    formattedSubject = articleAbstract;
    return formattedSubject;
}
```

Please note that as I said before, even if I don't actually use the `state` parameter, I still get the same results.

Here is my **`cellForRowAtIndexPath`** code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    
    News *news = newsArray[indexPath.row];
    
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if([selectedIndexPath isEqual:indexPath]) {
        cell.textLabel.attributedText = [news formattedSubject:1];
    }
    else {
        cell.textLabel.attributedText = [news formattedSubject:0];
    }

    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    UIView *selectedBackgroundViewForCell = [UIView new];
    [selectedBackgroundViewForCell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.169 green:0.322 blue:0.525 alpha:1.0]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundViewForCell;
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    if (indexPath.row == [newsArray count] - 1) {
        [self parseJSON];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Please let me know if I can post anything else that may help.

## Edit 2:

I'm not exactly sure if there is a performance issue. Upon further testing, I am inclined to believe that in Scenario A, the app loads and formats the cell data **before** displaying it, while in Scenario B, the app loads the data, displays it in the `UITableViewCell`, and **then** formats it, which creates the problem I detailed above.

Some people have brought up the code in my `parseJSON` method, so I'm posting it here for reference. As you can see I do indeed implement multithreading in order to prevent the data loading from lagging the application.

```
-(void)parseJSON
{
    loading.alpha = 1;
    loading.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading.png"];
    activityIndicator.alpha = 1;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(checkLoading) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        parseNumber = parseNumber + 1;
        int offset = parseNumber*20-1;
        NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://feedurl.com/feed.php?offset=%d",offset];
        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
        NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSError* error;
        if(data!=nil) {
            json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
            for(NSDictionary *newsInfo in json) {
                News *newsList = [[News alloc] init];
                newsList.thread = newsInfo[@"thread"];
                newsList.author = newsInfo[@"author"];
                newsList.subject = newsInfo[@"subject"];
                newsList.body= newsInfo[@"body"];
                newsList.datestamp = newsInfo[@"datestamp"];
                [jsonTemp addObject:newsList];
            }
            newsArray = jsonTemp;
        }
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if(data!=nil) {
                [newsTable reloadData];
            }
            else {
                activityIndicator.alpha = 0;
                loading.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"error.png"];
                [self startTimer];
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 for Nice explanation but what you have tried on code. can we see it?

Comment: Please, post your code inside `formattedSubject:`.

Comment: In a compiled and optimized language as objective-c calling `[object method]` or `[object method:1]` doesn't have any significant speed difference.

Comment: So what, do you think I'm just imagining this?

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think that NSAttributedString is the main problem. If You would simply use UILabels, then You would not see this kind of problem. Similarly I've noticed, that UIWebview content loading also takes fraction of a second to load content - because it is heavy. NSAttributedString also is heavy, but maybe just the right amount of heavy-ness to not notice any problems. (And when You start using a bit slower method [object method:1] -You start noticing problems). It would be interesting if You could test this on a slow device, with [object method]. Would it still work perfectly?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if there is a performance issue. Upon further testing, I am inclined to believe that in Scenario A, the app loads and formats the cell data **before** displaying it, while in Scenario B, the app loads the data, displays it in the `UITableViewCell`, and **then** formats it, which creates the problem I detailed in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Okay, there's a difference when calling `[news formattedSubject]` instead of `[news formattedSubject:1]`. The first one is like doing `news.formattedSubject`, this is, access the formattedSubject property that returns the ivar immediately, pretty fast. The second one calls the more complex `formattedSubject:` method that executes the code you posted, slower.

**Original:**

Your code seems fine except for some minor details like:

```
NSDictionary *boldStyle = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
```

not being necessary because you assign just afterwards:

```
boldStyle = @{NSFontAttributeName ...}
```

Also, what I guess could be causing your problem is:

```
if (indexPath.row == [newsArray count] - 1) {
    [self parseJSON];
}
```

Calling this inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath: could be a severe performance problem. If this method does a lot of work and does not do it in a background it could cause the delays you mention. As a rule of thumb, you should never do network/data processing in the main thread (cellForRowAtIndexPath will always be called in that thread by the system).

Comment: I implemented multithreading in the parseJSON method. All the data is loaded into an array in the background, and after that is done it populates and reloads the UITableView in the main thread. I can post the code tomorrow if you want, going to bed now.

Answer (score 0):

You says like below

"The text in each table view cell is roughly 3-5 lines in length, and is **read from an external source and parsed via JSON**. Here's a diagram of the desired result, which is what happens in Scenario A:"

I assume that you are reading data from

1.Local Core data Database

or

2.Web server's database.

For case 1, you should use NSFetchedResultsController, follow up this tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

For case 2 you should do in background thread,and update it by Main thread in tableview, when it is available,  follow up this tutorial

[How to load JSON asynchronously (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19261081/how-to-load-json-asynchronously-ios)

Comment: I tried commenting out that line, but I still get the same result. There is still that brief moment where the data has been loaded, but not yet formatted. Also, how does this explain why there is no performance issue when there is no `state` parameter?

Comment: The data is being read from a web server, and I already am using asynchronous requests to load data.